# Least LESS files for Bootstrap (latest)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I couldn't find anywhere which less files are required for a minimum Bootstrap website design.

I just want to download the LESS files from github, modify to get my own theme and compile the CSS.

The website should be responsive of course and have only navigation, grid system, typography and buttons.

What are the minimum required LESS files to compile the right CSS? No fuss such as panels, wells, tables etc is needed!

Many thanks for any recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it in [its sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less) as well, they are the following:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.lessimport";
@import "mixins.lessimport";

// Reset
@import "normalize.lessimport";
@import "print.lessimport";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.lessimport";
@import "type.lessimport";
@import "code.lessimport";
@import "grid.lessimport";
@import "tables.lessimport";
@import "forms.lessimport";
@import "buttons.lessimport";
```

So you'd only have to comment out the rest of [the file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less) and recompile the whole thing. And you should get the desired results